# 12.04 upgrade stops at 'mysql restarting'

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, mysql

After downloading the upgrade started but the script stopped at 'mysql restarting'. What should I do now? The system doesn't launch any application and doesn't accept any commands.  Should I reboot and hope for the best?

Answer (score 2):

For me the following worked:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> - log in and then run:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I typed: ps -aux in terminal, then I found PID of processes restarting mysql and killed one of them (the first one, there were three of them), the installation went on and then the same problem occured one more time. I did exactly the same thing - killed the process; since then everything's going well - I hope it will be fine after the installation.

Comment: `ps -aux | grep mysql` found two processes for me with the last one being grep, and the first one being the appropriate process to kill with a swift `sudo kill ####`.